# Minor Issue when doing method overriding in SONAR

Tags: java, inheritance, sonarqube, overriding

Approach one: Issue is

Description Assignee    Resource    New issue
    - Useless Overriding Method : Overriding method merely calls super
    - overrides 
     A.executeImpl

```
class A {

protected void executeImpl(){
 // blah blah
}}

class B extends A{

protected void executeImpl(){

super.executeImpl();
}}

class C{

@Inject B b;

protected void executeCall(){

b.executeImpl();
}
}
```

if i remove overriden method:
Java Error: 
The method executeImpl() from the type B is not 
 visible

```
class A {

protected void executeImpl(){
 // blah blah
}}



class B extends A{

}



class C{

@Inject B b;

protected void executeCall(){

b.executeImpl();
}
}
```

What shall be my approach to remove the sonar minor issue .

Comment: Please add the package structure of `A`, `B` and `C`.

Comment: Class A was in diff package, While B and C are in Same package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you have to rethink your package structure. I think `A` is in another package than `B` and `C`. So `C` can't access the protected method in `A` but if you override it in `B`, `C` can access it.

- You could make `executeImpl()` public in `A`.
- Move `A`, `B` and `C` all to the same package or
- just ignore this issue or mark it as false
  positive with an explanation.

Comment: 2 option is the thing which was causing problem.